Create a keyboard shortcut to make a selection-dependent hyperlink?
I'd like to create a keyboard shortcut, say Ctrl+H, that replaces some text XYZ with ButtonBox["XYZ", BaseStyle -> "Link", ButtonData -> "http://arxiv.org/pdf/XYZ"]. I attempted to add the following to KeyEventTranslations.tr:
Item[
    KeyEvent["h", Modifiers -> {"Control"}], 
    FrontEndExecute[
        FrontEnd`NotebookApply[
            FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], 
            ButtonBox[
                "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 
                BaseStyle -> "Link", 
                ButtonData -> "http://arxiv.org/pdf/\[SelectionPlaceholder]"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

But only the first instance of \[SelectionPlaceholder] gets replaced with XYZ. The documentation suggests this is intended behavior. If this were part of a button, I could use NotebookRead to get the selection and manipulate it more freely, but I haven't been able to get this to work in the form of a keyboard shortcut. Is this possible?
